# Sort algorithms illustration on wikipedia?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, wikipedia

Can anyone explain to me what the "Graphical illustrations" of sorting algorithms on Wikipedia mean? I can't understand them.

**Bubble sort**

[image: Bubble Sort - Wikipedia]

**Insertion sort**

[image: Insertion Sort - Wikipedia]

Comment: Each line represents an element in the array being sorted, and as it moves up or down in the picture, that is showing how that element moves through the array thoughout the sorting procedure.

Comment: @Nactive There's plenty of times I've been stuck at something and been glad to see that someone has answered a question I had that was obvious to them (but not to me). This site wouldn't be half as big as it is if we all didn't struggle sometimes at things that others find easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are the locations of the various elements in an array (and looks like the gray tone indicates the numerical value). The lines show the process of the sort, the X axis is the time, and on each time step one or more elements are moved, until on the right hand side you can see them sorted by the tone.

The distinction here is that a bubble-sort would take a single element and start swapping adjacent elements (so you can see the dark gray element slowly propagating to the end, until it hits a darker one, and you continue with that one).

Insertion sort, on the other hand, takes a single element, decides where to insert it, and shifts the rest of the elements accordingly, you can see this represented by several parallel diagonal lines all moving at the same time.

This is a nice illustration, but try to read the algorithmic description - it's not very complicated, and maybe then the illustration would make more sense to you.

Another possible benefit of these illustrations is that they may give you a hunch on the number of actions needed to sort an array - even though it's for a single given example and not necessarily the worst case. Both bubble sort and insert sort are of the magnitude of O(n^2), n being the number of elements. This means that as n grows, you're looking into quite a lot of actions (swaps or insertions). 
This is why they came up with other sort algorithms with better complexity (up to O(n*logn), you can't beat that in the general case), see for e.g. quick sort; and also algorithms relying on additional constraints, such as that the sorted numbers are bounded from above (bin sort / radix sort)

Comment: Very nice explanation. I'll be honest, I've been on the page he's referring to many times, and I never realized that the shade corresponds to the value of the elements. Great catch there.

Comment: I never knew they had illustrations for that in wikipedia. Just looked at the ones for merge sort and quicksort - pretty nice :-)